# Is relative extrema a number or a point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

I was told that relative (local) extrema are only a number -- its $y$ value only. However, from a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=is%20local%20extrema%20a%20point&sxsrf=APq-WBvMXGITbdzOO5_CNiA9ZPqWRHCedA%3A1651122574988&ei=jiFqYv_7O67K0PEPr9inyAI&ved=0ahUKEwj_-r_0_rX3AhUuJTQIHS_sCSkQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=is%20local%20extrema%20a%20point&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIFCAAQogQ6BwgjELADECc6BwgAEEcQsANKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQ2gFY2gFg-wNoAXABeACAAXuIAXuSAQMwLjGYAQCgAQHIAQnAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) and a book, it is written as a "point" instead. That is, it is an ordered pair of $x$ and $y$ values. Which one is correct? In addition, if it is a point, what's the difference of it and a critical point?

Specifically, the google search quotes Brilliant.org's ["Extrema (Local and Absolute)" entry](https://brilliant.org/wiki/extrema/): "An extremum (or extreme **value**) of a function is a **point** ...", while in the book it specifically asks for the extrema **point**.

Comment: Both terms "extreme points" and "extreme values" can be reduced to "extrema" to improve readability of text, so context matters.

Comment: @Blue but the google search says "An extremum (or extreme **value**) of a function is a **point**"...

Comment: Add that particular quote to the body of your question so that people don't have to click through the link. ... I concur the phrasing is problematic in asserting that a *value* is a *point*; bear in mind that it was written by a human, and humans occasionally use less-than-perfect grammar. That said, it's not uncommon to conflate an object (like a point) with a measurement (its $y$ coordinate). We do it all the time in, say, geometry, where a letter can represent both an angle and its measure, or a segment and its length. Math is a *language*; like any other, it has its ambiguities.

Comment: Usually, the convention is that an extremum/minimum/maximum is a value and a minimizer/maximizer (never seen extremizer :D) is the corresponding point.

Comment: @cvanaret: Interesting. I don't recall ever seeing "minimizer/maximizer" in this context, certainly not for the *point*. (To the extent that a "-mizer" is a "thing that *-mizes*", it might reasonably be considered the corresponding $x$-value (also known as the "arg[ument]-max/min").) I'm not saying you're wrong, of course. This goes to a broader point (or value?) that math has no governing body establishing uniform terminology; conventions can, and do, differ. (I always like to note that we can't even agree on whether [zero is a natural number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number).)

Comment: Sorry if my message was misleading, I did mean the argmin/argmax. What did you mean by "point"?